# Mostrar produtos de 2 categorias na página (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

estou com uma dúvida. Como faço para mostrar produtos de 2 categorias em uma página com woocommerce, como se fosse um filtro? Tentei fazer criando a página com o shortcode do plugin, mas não deu certo:

```
[product_categories number="20,17" parent="0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

O shortcode está errado. O number especifica a quantidade de produtos. Para as caetgorias você deve usar "ids":

```
[product_categories number="12" parent="0" ids="20,17"]
```

Se quiser mostrar todas as categorias de nível superior:

```
[product_categories number="12" parent="0"]
```